# Call function with arguments by name - Arguments aren't pushed correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
class OfferHandler:
    def get(provider, **kwargs):
        getattr(OfferHandler, 'get_' + provider)(**kwargs)

    def get_ADM(settings, ip, uniquekey):
        return settings

 x = OfferHandler
 settings = x.get('ADM', '{json settings}', '127.0.0.1', '123')
 pprint(settings) # prints Null instead of {json settings}
```

Why arguments aren't pushed correctly?

Comment: Fix thine indent please.

Comment: Why is `OfferHandler` a class here? You are not using it as a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using keyword arguments, only positional arguments.

If you use keyword arguments they can actually be captured by `**kwargs` and passed on:

```
settings = x.get('ADM', settings='{json settings}', ip='127.0.0.1', uniquekey='123')
```

Note that you are not actually using `OfferHandler` as a class; you appear to be using it as a namespace instead. Use Python modules to create namespaces instead; `class` should really only be used for actual classes, so objects you mean to create instances of.